# LEFT OUTER JOIN on two Dictionary<int, string> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to do a left outer join with two `Dictionary<int, string>` objects. These are the objects:

```
            var leftSet = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "Michael"},
                { 2, "John" },
                { 3, "Bill" }
            };

            var rightSet = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "Another Michael"},
                { 3, "Another Bill" },
                { 4, "Tony" }
            };
```

I write the query like this:

```
var queryResult = from leftElements in leftSet
                  join rightElements in rightSet
                     on leftElements.Key equals rightElements.Key into joinResult
                  from result in joinResult
                  select new { leftElements.Key, result.Value };
```

This results in an inner join instead of the left outer join that I wanted. I know I need to grab `leftElements.Key` before it becomes part of `joinResult`, but then I wouldn't know how to write the `select` statement afterwards.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 from result in joinResult
```

to:

```
 from result in joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

to accomplish a left outer join.

Everything else can remain the same.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I'm trying to get my head around why this works. I checked the result right after ```joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()``` executes, and the result contains three elements, of which ```{ 2, "John" }``` is _not_ a member. So I don't understand where the ```select``` statement is grabbing it from.

Comment: @InvalidBrainException good question!. because I am quite busy at this moment in time, I will refer you to **two** things which you should read and it won't take long, the first being the [documentation on left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) and the second being [documentation on DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_DefaultIfEmpty__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

Comment: @InvalidBrainException if you're still confused after reading both of these then feel free to leave a comment saying so and when I am free I will get back to you. Although it's getting a bit late here in England so not sure when exactly I'd get back to you :).

Comment: Thanks for the links -- I've read them, and the main takeaway for me is that a join followed by ```DefaultIfEmpty()``` is simply how a left outer join is done in LINQ. That's basically what the second paragraph in the first link says! However, when I break it down and investigate the results of each line of the query, the result of ```joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()``` does not contain the element ```{2, "John"}```, yet the ```select``` at the end somehow brings it back! My hunch is that LINQ is doing something smart behind the scenes. Thanks for your help thus far.